# How we can update multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

How can update multiple tables using single query.I have to update two tables at a time. I tried this query but it fails to update

```
UPDATE  contact,bill SET companyid =2  WHERE  userid=1 AND companyid =20;
```

Comment: Why do you HAVE to update two tables at a time.  Can't you just run two queries?

Comment: Please post your table structure and, if you get an error, post that as well...

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
UPDATE contact INNER JOIN bill SET companyid =2 WHERE userid=1 AND companyid =20;
```

Or to prevent conflicts.( Unsure of your table layout but heres the rough idea )

```
UPDATE contact x INNER JOIN bill y SET x.companyid =2 WHERE x.userid=1 AND y.companyid =20;
```

Comment: This will probably raise an error (didn't tested it). SET companyid=2 will not know which table to update (supposing both tables have companyid as the user is trying to update).

Comment: @Eddie I'm not sure but I think, on doing an open join such as this, you can express the same with `table1, table1` which is what the OP has. Is there a difference?

Comment: @Parkyprg simply use alias's then.

Comment: this query gives me error #1052 - Column 'companyid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @Aneesh You need to alias the tables to prevent this. POst your table structure and Eddie's answer can be more informative as at the moment, he cannot show aliasing without knowing which column is for which table...

Answer (score 2):

If the reason you "have to update two tables at a time" is to ensure that the changes don't get half done, then you may want to consider wrapping your queries in a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ...
UPDATE ...
COMMIT;
```

(Or whatever the MySQL syntax is...)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update in the same time.

```
UPDATE contact SET companyid=2 WHERE userid=1 AND companyid =20;
UPDATE bill    SET companyid=2 WHERE userid=1 AND companyid =20;
```

Comment: Yes you can; see `Multiple-table syntax`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @Brendan: Show an example. In your reference, multiple tables are used for joins.

Comment: You simply need to inner join them.

Comment: @Eddie: Check my comment on your post.

Comment: @Parkyprg See this thread: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,85813,85813#msg-85813 The important part is aliasing tables to ensure there are no ambiguity errors